# Can I simply copy jre folder to another location?

Tags: linux, java, centos

I downloaded the bin file, and installed it but I haven't realized that I made the folder in the current directory. I would like to install in `/usr/java`.

1. Can I now just copy paste it there.
2. Or I need to re-install to desired location
3. I installed JRE , is that ok or I need to install sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development, you need the java development kit, jdk.
Otherwise, the jre is fine.

It is quite possible to copy the jre folder to the `/usr/java`.
Make sure to add its location to the `PATH` variable.
Check where does `java`  point to -> `which java`
Afterwards, check its target.
 E.g. `ls -al /usr/bin/java`

The chain should end up in your jre folder.